# Spliting string for specific number of spaces - C#

Tags: c#, string, split, substring

I have a string `North Ridge NJ 01234` I want to split them into City, State and zip to store into Database. I was trying to split based on spaces, I get four substrings instead of three. Is there any way I can split backwards but only on two spaces?

Comment: Does anything prevent you getting strings like "North Ridge New Jersey 01234" or "North Ridge,NJ 01234"?

Comment: So you want city, state zip?

Comment: There are lots of ways to achieve that manually, but I guess there could be no universal pattern for the code unless your string follows some certain format of the data. But if it's only a random spacing and different counts of words, then it'll be hard to figure it out.

Comment: yes, the data layout I have is Two Alphabet state.

Comment: @GibralterTop I want three substrings, City State Zip

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui Is yor city ALWAYS 2 word and are the other two members of data ALWAYS 1 word?

Comment: @D.Petrov in my data layout zip is numeric, state is two alphabet and city is random. I don't want to do it manually because there are 5000+ rows

Comment: @D.Petrov some cities are one word, some are two words

Comment: I think what Umm is asking for is code that will read the string backwords  (from the right) and pull the first value as zip second as State and third as city. 
Isnt that correct?

Comment: @DaniDev I think we all get the idea of the code's purpose, since we're humans, but you can't tell the computer which two or three words make up a name of a state or a city. So that's the main issue here, reading it forwards or backwards won't matter that much. We shall concentrate on an intelligent way of achieving it, but I still think there is no such according to the circumstances.

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui I could suggest that you can take away your last string as the ZIP and then, maybe, [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925195/making-state-abbreviations-from-state-names) could help. The idea is to match the full name or the abreviature of the state and find it that way. Could work fine with a bit of string modification (to make it more exact), since the states are only 52 :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can assume the last array element is the ZIP and the one before that the state code

```
string[] words = s.Split(' ');

var zip = words[words.Length - 1];
var state = words[words.Length - 2];
var city = string.Join(" ", words, 0, words.Length - 2);
```

Makes use of a [string.Join overloa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx)d that lets you specify the start index and number of array elements to join.

Note that the code can fail if the assumptions fail to hold. For example, if it is possible for data to be delimited by either space or tab, you will want to provide both characters to string.Split(). If it is possible that bad data entry could lead to multiple space characters, you'll want to check for that possibility before running this code (e.g. `New York, NY  12345`).

Comment: Perhaps you should concider splitting not only by space, since it's not sure if it's the only delimeter... We can still not be sure if the state is only one word tho, so this will most likely be the best but still not universal method to achieve the goal...

Comment: As long as the space is the delimiter between the city portion, the state portion and the ZIP portion it will work fine. If there are other quirks of the format, the OP would need to be clear about what they are.

Comment: With limited information on input possibilities, this is the best approach

Comment: @OzanGunceler Exactly what I meant.

Comment: `String.Split` has an overload allowing to specify the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option. This would help removing multiple and trailing split characters  (like `", "`).

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple regular expression.

```
> string test = "North Ridge NJ 01234";
> Regex address = new Regex(@"([\w ]*) (\w\w) (\d\d\d\d\d)");
> address.Split(test)
string[5] { "", "North Ridge", "NJ", "01234", "" }
```

If anyone knows a way to not get the empty strings back, I'd love to hear it. This should work for any address you have of this form, though.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    string s = "North Ridge NJ 01234";

    //Following gives {01234, NJ, Ridge, North}
    var words = s.Split(' ').ToList();
    words.Reverse();

    string zip = words[0];
    string state = words[1];
    string city = s.Replace(state + " " + zip, "");
}
```

Comment: To whoever voted down, you make no sense. It works as the OP desires.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer as it will work in a practical sense for real data. If you had input data "NJ 01234 NJ 01234" it would fail. `words.Reverse()` is a bit unnecessary. It creates a duplicate of the original array, whereas you could just process the array in reverse instead. s.Replace() creates the edge case mentioned before where it could fail for an edge case.

Comment: OP stated they wanted a way to "split backwards" which is why I included `.Reverse()`. Also, there are no edge cases where the city name is the abbreviation plus the zip code. I checked.

Comment: I know there are no real data cases that would fail, but at some point in the future, someone might reuse the same code for a similar but different problem where the edge case can occur.

Comment: Okay, your hypothetical scenario says that they may insert "NJ 01234 North Ridge" at which point, your answer would be wrong as well.

Comment: Er, no. That's not what I said. Look back over my comments.

Comment: Yeah, that is what you said. If they want to reuse it to input "NJ 01234 NJ 01234" then they might reuse it to input "NJ 01234 North Ridge". They might even put in "North+Ridge+NJ+01234". Plus, why would they want NJ 01234 twice in a string. If they want the state and zip code, this sets state and zip code. So for your edge case, you still set the state and zip code and forget the rest. So, still works on your edge case if people want to extract state and zip code from the end of the string.

Comment: My point is what if people use the same code to process something that is not city, state, zip but follows a similar processing pattern. Seen plenty of bugs in this type of situation in code that is in maintenance mode.

Comment: My point is it works as the OP wanted and included a way to "split backwards". Therefore, reinforcing my original comment as your downvote makes no sense as this question is SPECIFICALLY for city, state, zip.

Comment: `I didn't downvote the answer as it will work in a practical sense for real data` you are arguing with the wrong person about the downvotes. I didn't downvote you. I did take the time to explain why I think the answer is less than optimal. Take that advice however you want to.